# Regex to accept Min 6 characters, at least one letter and at least one of the following: 0123456789-.@_

Tags: javascript, regex, html, regex-group

I want a single Regex to accept:

1. Min 6 characters
2. at least one letter
3. at least one of the following: `0123456789-.@_`

I have tried :

```
 ^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[._@-])[A-Za-z\d._@-]{1,40}$
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I tried this regex but it will not solve my problem.

^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[._@-])[A-Za-z\d._@-]{1,40}$

Comment: you'd think your quantifier would be `{6,40}` if your minimum length is 6

Comment: your regex would require at least 1 a-zA-Z ... at least one digit AND at least one of those other characters ... try combining the digit and special character lookaheads

Comment: can the other characters be anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\d.@_-]).{6,}$
```

[Regex Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/XFlBMp/1)

Or if you don't want any characters but only the mentioned ones to form your entire string then you may try the following as well:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\d.@_-])[a-zA-Z\d.@_-]{6,40}$
```

[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/XFlBMp/2)

Sample Source for demo 1:

```js
const regex = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\d.@_-]).{6,}$/g;
console.log(regex.test(`0a123456789-.@_`));
console.log(regex.test(`abcdefghijklmn`));
console.log(regex.test(`0a123456789`));
console.log(regex.test(`0a12`));
```

Comment: Then would encourage you to accept the answer... https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers